# How to convert text in ANSEL to UTF-8 in php

Tags: php, encoding, iconv, genealogy, gedcom

I have a php script working with GEDCOM files, which are often using ANSEL encoding. I did not found any solution to convert them properly to UTF-8 charset.
Is there a way using for example iconv or I have to make my own solution as suggested here [How to convert ANSEL text to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359942/how-to-convert-ansel-text-to-utf-8) for C#?

ANSEL wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSEL

Comment: Have a look at Gramps ANSEL to Unicode Conversion code
 https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps/blob/c5f2717623d4fa301c16014dac29c281cf3baf3e/gramps/plugins/lib/libgedcom.py#L1171

Comment: Thank You, I will consider transcoding into PHP.